# How to connect Media Player to a SeekBar?

Tags: android, media-player

I want to show the progress of a media on a seekbar.
Also I want to allow user to "jump" within a medium.

I have a MediaPlayer, and a SeekBar. And as far as I see there is no an easy way to merge them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VideoView instead of MediaPlayer and you can have MediaController which can be set to VideoView.

Otherwise you have to get the progress at instances and update the seek bar you can use timers.

Comment: The problem is that I need to play both Video and Music files. So the problem will occur eventually.