# How to add SeekBar in the MainActivity of Music Player

Tags: android

I am wondering if I can add a seekbar in main.xml and control it through the MainActivity.java.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html

Comment: Seems an exact duplicate of the first post in the related section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829679/how-to-connect-media-player-to-a-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](https://sapandiwakar.in/building-a-music-player-app-for-android/) that I wrote that explains how to manually create the controls for Android Media Player.